# MS graph API: Set custom tags (columns) of a DriveItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-documents

I am using ms graph in order to upload files into a document library. 
I have implemented a code for large files and it works
but I have no idea how to set the custom columns of the "drive"

here is my code. I have played with the additionalData but I did not succeed.

Any thought??

thanks

```
     public static async Task<DriveItem> uploadFile()
            {
                Stream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\prueba\prueba2.xlsx", FileMode.Open);
                DriveItem uploadedFile = null;
                UploadSession uploadSession = null;

    uploadSession = await objGraphServiceClient.Sites["SITE_ID"].Lists["LIST-ID"].Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("EISE_PRUEBA2.xlsx").CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();

 if (uploadSession != null)
            {
                // Chunk size must be divisible by 320KiB, our chunk size will be slightly more than 1MB 
                int maxSizeChunk = (320 * 1024 * 10) * 4;
                ChunkedUploadProvider uploadProvider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(uploadSession, objGraphServiceClient, fileStream, maxSizeChunk);
                var chunkRequests = uploadProvider.GetUploadChunkRequests();
                var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
                var readBuffer = new byte[maxSizeChunk];

                foreach (var request in chunkRequests)
                {


                       var result = await uploadProvider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(request, readBuffer, exceptions);



                    if (result.UploadSucceeded)
                    {
                        uploadedFile = result.ItemResponse;

                        var uno = uploadedFile.AdditionalData;

                        var add = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                        add.Add("PositionCode", "Pos-01-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmmm"));
                        add.Add("Category", "Category_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmmm"));

                        var temp = new ListItem();
                        temp.Id = uploadedFile.Id;
                        temp.Fields = new FieldValueSet();
                        temp.Fields.AdditionalData = add;


                        var driveItem = new DriveItem();

                        //var users = await objGraphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

                        //    var driveItem = new DriveItem
                        //    {
                        //        Name = "new-file-name.xlsx"

                        //    };
                        //    //driveItem.CreatedByUser = users.First();
                        //    driveItem.AdditionalData =  new Dictionary<string, object>();

                        //    driveItem.AdditionalData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@odata.category", "Category" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmmm")));
                        //    driveItem.AdditionalData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@odata.PositionCode", "Pos-01-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmmm")));


                        // var updatedItem = await objGraphServiceClient.Sites["hispaniaassetmanagement.sharepoint.com,d04053f4-eb19-4ed8-9785-0f7aa2a908c8,6227bfe6-c7cb-4990-8f51-0a7fd8c28c1b"].Lists["67987e61-86cc-4f3e-93f2-0b6699b97a94"].Drive.Items[uploadedFile.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(driveItem);
                        //objGraphServiceClient.Sites["hispaniaassetmanagement.sharepoint.com,d04053f4-eb19-4ed8-9785-0f7aa2a908c8,6227bfe6-c7cb-4990-8f51-0a7fd8c28c1b"].Lists["67987e61-86cc-4f3e-93f2-0b6699b97a94"].Drive.Items["017ZCPK2DMW4ZEXUK7QZHJ7CQLPY7GHDFJ"]

                        uploadedFile.ListItem.Fields.AdditionalData = add;

                        var updatedItem = await objGraphServiceClient.Sites["SITE-ID"].Lists["LIST-ID"].Drive.List.Items[uploadedFile.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(uploadedFile.ListItem);
                    }
                }
            }
            return (uploadedFile);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "set the custom columns of the 'drive'". What error are you getting?

Comment: sorry, in a documentLib we have created more custom columns as category, subcategory, etc... when we upload the document using the MS graph library I have no idea how to set that values. thanks

Comment: I do not want to list them. I want o set them. by the way I am using the MS graph API

Comment: You misunderstand. In a Document Library, each `DriveItem` has an associated `ListItem` that holds it's metadata (i.e. custom columns). These must be addressed as distinct entities using separate API calls.

Comment: I don't think this was a duplicate.  Getting custom metadata (as discussed in question 55071910) didn't tell me that to _set_ the fields I needed to PATCH the `fields` and which version of the URL would work, as the answer below did.  This might be just because I haven't grokked all the Sharepoint data relationships yet, but I didn't really want to have to do that in order to keep progressing on my work, and to me that's what Stack Overflow is all about.  An example to follow was super-useful!

Comment: Agree - this is not a duplicate - this is about updating the field - not just reading their values

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution using the rest API insead the SDK.
using graph explorer would be:

PATCH: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{ListId}/items/{ItemId}/fields

Content-type: application/json

{
  "customColumn": "value"
}

---

BUT!!! if you want update the fileds of an uploaded file which returns a drive item the solution would be

```
 var result = await uploadProvider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(request, readBuffer, exceptions);

                if (result.UploadSucceeded)
                {
                    uploadedFile = result.ItemResponse;

                    string webApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/"+ siteIDDMS + "/drives/"+driveIDHAMSLib+"/items/"+uploadedFile.Id+"/listItem/fields";

                    JObject paramsJson = new JObject()
                    {
                        ["Category"] = "NewCat_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmmm")                            
                    };

                    await RunRestApi(webApiUrl, accessToken, paramsJson,"PATCH", Display);

                }
```

**By the way... somebody know if this is achievable using the SDK???**

Comment: Can be done using graph api in this way:
    var putFileRequest = _graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drives[driveId].Root.ItemWithPath(fileName).Content.Request();
    var fileItem = await putFileRequest.PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
    var updateFileTagsRequest = _graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drives[driveId].Items[fileItem.Id].ListItem.Fields.Request();
    var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet
    { AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>{{ "ContentType", "Log" },{ "Document_Status", "Active" }}};
    await updateFileTagsRequest.UpdateAsync(fieldValueSet);

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! update using the driveId instead of itemID!